# Can't implement SMS Verification into my android app

Tags: java, android

i'm now making android apps, so here is my VerifyOTP class ,  I'm getting E/zzbf: SafetyNet Attestation fails basic integrity. error ...

Can Someone please help me .

this SafetyNet I just can't understand...

I've tried everything, the aplication should automatically entered Code given by SMS ... but when I enter my information in aplication, my phone number is passed by Intent ... end used in sendVerificationCodeToUser()...

```
public class VerifyOTP extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Variables
    PinView pinFromUser;
    ImageView closeBtn;
    String codeBySystem;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify_o_t_p);

        // Hooks
        pinFromUser = findViewById(R.id.pin_view);
        closeBtn = findViewById(R.id.otp_close_btn);

        String _phoneNo = getIntent().getStringExtra("phone");

        sendVerificationCodeToUser(_phoneNo);

        closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                VerifyOTP.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCodeToUser(String phone) {

        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(phone)       // Phone number to verify
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                        .setActivity(this)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                        .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                        .build();
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);

    }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks =
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String s, @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
                    super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
                    codeBySystem = s;

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {

                    String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
                    if (code != null) {
                        pinFromUser.setText(code);
                        verifyCode(code);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {

                    Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            };

    private void verifyCode(String code) {
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(codeBySystem, code);
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Verification Completed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                            if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {

                                Toast.makeText(VerifyOTP.this, "Verification failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public void CallNextFromOTP(View view) {
        String code = pinFromUser.getText().toString();
        if (!code.isEmpty()) {
            verifyCode(code);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you add at `AndroidManifest.xml`  these permissions ?

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Comment: hey! thanks for answer! ... i added it but its still the same, it reddirects me to recaptcha in browser ( btw sometimes recaptcha generates sometimes not) and than reddirects back to app.

Comment: i think because your code is missing premission check function

Answer (score 0):

i think because your code is missing premission check function that's why send you to navigation add this code to your code in `VerifyOTP.java`

```java
private void checkForSmsPermission() {
   if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.permission_not_granted));
       // Permission not yet granted. Use requestPermissions().
       // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS is an
       // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
       // result of the request.
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
   } else {
       // Permission already granted. Enable the SMS button.
       enableSmsButton();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add these dependencies in your build.gradle :**

implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0"

Firebase Quote "The reCAPTCHA flow will only be triggered when SafetyNet is unavailable or your device does not pass suspicion checks. Nonetheless, you should ensure that both scenarios are working correctly." So to enable SafetyNet, follow the below steps or you can also visit [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)  for more info.

1. Go to google cloud console, select your project.
2. Click on the navigation menu and select APis & services and then select Dashboard.
3. Click on enable api and services and enable api " Android Device Verification".
4. Add SHA 256 in firebase project settings.(debug and release both)
5. Download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.